# Is there a way to attack-move in Age of Empires II: HD?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I've just bought Age of Empires II: HD, and have been running through the tutorial missions to re-skill up (it's been a while since I played the original). On the last map of the tutorial I built up a sizeable army and told them to move toward the enemy base, however I couldn't figure out how to tell them to attack-move, i.e. attack any enemy on the path to where I clicked.

I've been through the keybinds, but I haven't seen anything. Is there a way to attack-move in AoE2:HD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expansion [The Forgotten](http://store.steampowered.com/app/239550/) now includes an attack-move command, which is bound to tab.

Comment: tab? that's an interesting choice. I'll have to check it out when I get home

Comment: I've been getting poor results with `tab`, although it may be due to the dated AI in general. Units will often spend many seconds trying to path to a distant unit whilst ignoring those that are nearby.

Answer (score 12):

This answer applies to all AoE 2 variants, from the original to the Conquerors expansion to the HD release.  There is no attack-move in AoE 2.  Right-clicking on an enemy unit will order your military units to pursue and attack that unit, ignoring everything else along the way.  If the target moves out of line of sight or dies, your military units simply stop where they are and return their stance behavior.  For this reason, it is inadvisable to right click on any target not in range of your units, as your units will spend most of their time walking and accomplish very little before dying.

AoE 2 does have a mechanic that is similar to attack-move, called patrol.  I believe you have to turn on advanced commands (F4 by default) in order to enable it.  I like to call patrol "attack-move-in-circles", because that is essentially how it works.  The patrol command lets you set waypoints with shift click, and is finalized with a right click.  Once you do that, your units will "attack-move" along that route, returning to their starting location after the final waypoint.

Comment: I like the patrol workaround, I will have to give that a go. Will they attack passive structures (walls, houses etc) whilst "patrolling"?

Comment: I believe patrol will cause them to attack buildings.  Units on patrol don't stay together as a group very well.  A skillful and wily opponent could pull small groups of units at a time by entering the very edge of their line of sight, and finish them off piecemeal.  One downside of patrol is you can't find patrolling units with the idle units command.  You will thus need to keep a very close eye on your patrolling units.

Comment: This is the better answer IMO -- something in-game rather than using an expansion.

Comment: @TimS. - Both answers are fine, but the expansion solved the problem I was having exactly, as opposed to a workaround (which is still fine). This was the original accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

On the advanced commands panel,there is a button called "attack-move".It was added in "The Forgotten".